# Влияет ли союз «а» на использование либо «не», либо «»

Tags: орфография

Как корректно? С *ни* иль *не*?

> Сколько поэм, да стишок, да письмецов Леопольд Лизавете, отчаянный, в ночи **не/ни** писал, сколько бы ей **не/ни** говорил: «Мне так с тобою важна наша дружба!» — **а** она его по-прежнему нипочём не прощает, оттого что он по-подлому рассказал при всех, кто с нею учился, днём одним серединноянварским «Монолог о позабытой дружбе», им же и сочинённый вверечу.

> Сколько бы раз я **не/ни** сказал той старушенции: «Леопольды не имеют нужды в пенсии, т. к., в старость впав, мы будем-таки жить на наших... акционных... дивидендах!» — она всё говорила: «Ах ты, проныра! Уж распоясался, смотрю-ка, здесь!»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ЧЕМУ БЫ жизнь нас ни учила,
НО сердце верит в чудеса:
Есть нескудеющая сила,
Есть и нетленная краса.
И увядание земное
Цветов не тронет неземных,
И от полуденного зноя
Роса не высохнет на них...

Автор: Ф. И. Тютчев
```

Правильно:

(1) ***Сколько** поэм, да стишков, да письмецов Леопольд Лизавете, отчаянный, в ночи **НИ писал**, сколько бы ей **НИ говорил**: «Мне так с тобою важна наша дружба!» — **а** она его по-прежнему нипочём не прощает...*

(2) ***Сколько бы** раз я **НИ сказал** той старушенции: «Леопольды не имеют нужды в пенсии, т. к., в старость впав, мы будем-таки жить на наших... акционных... дивидендах!»  — она всё говорила: «Ах ты, проныра! Уж распоясался, смотрю-ка, здесь!»*

**Пояснение**

1. Это предложения с **обобщенно-уступительным** значением и усилительной частицей ***НИ.*** Сочинительные союзы ***А*** и ***НО*** **акцентируют** уступительное значение, и тогда связь приобретает **подчинительно-сочинительный** характер. В то же время сочинительные союзы ***А*** и ***НО*** ***не являются*** обязательными.

Материал из **Русской Грамматики**, 1990 год, § 669.

Пример: ***Как ни** прекрасно было утро, **но** мы выехали в поле не так рано.* Придаточная часть сообщает, что **признак доведен до предела**, и, несмотря на это, результат получается **противоположный** тому, которого следовало ожидать.

2. В предложении (1) я бы использовала **единый знак** (запятая и тире) в качестве замены тире (обозначение увеличенной паузы): ряд придаточных в препозиции, значительная распространенность. Правомерность такой замены пока не определена, так что единый знак можно считать авторской пунктуацией (это дискуссионный вопрос).

**[Розенталь.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)**

Comment: Союз а со строчной пишется, после прямой речи запятая не нужна.

Comment: Это строчная буква, я ее просто выделила шрифтом (сейчас уберу). У меня единый знак (обозначение подчеркнутой паузы), а не просто запятая. Такое графическое оформление используется у Розенталя при встрече двух реплик. Я думаю, что здесь применима подобная графика, она не выглядит противоречиво. Впрочем, это смежная тема по этому вопросу, а не основная. Если категорически нельзя, то могу тоже убрать. Но пока я в этом не уверена. Использование единого знака (теория и практика) еще не в достаточной мере проработано в литературе.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что у вас придаточное предложение по факту финализируется аж двумя знаками: восклицательным и запятой.  Как часто предложения закрываются вот таким сочетанием - !,

Comment: Вопрос дискуссионный, а запятые я убрала, чтобы не отвлекать внимание от основной темы. Сейчас там нет запятых.

Comment: Не часто, но случается: Когда приходил к нему мужик и, почесавши рукою затылок, говорил: «Барин, позволь отлучиться на работу, подать заработать», — «Ступай», — говорил он (Г.) — запятая и тире разделяют две реплики разных лиц, находящиеся внутри слов автора.

Comment: И что? Я говорю о том, что восклицательный знак закрывает придаточное и нейтрализует собой запятую. В вашем примере запятая и тире разделяют реплики разных персонажей. Я про восклицательный и запятую, а вы мне про запятую и тире. Не хочу занудствовать, но я у вас одно спросил — о сочетании восклицательного знака и запятой в конце придаточного, — а вы мне ответили что-то другое.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше внимание к ответу.  Я  хотела сказать, что  в первой реплике можно использовать воскл. или вопрос. знак, потом поставить запятую и тире. // В нашей теме надо было соединить правило о едином знаке после ряда придаточных (там требуется увел. пауза) и правило оформления прямой речи. // Кроме того,  союз А не совсем обычен в теме придаточных, так что надо было графически  выделить сочинительную связь.  // Вот такая у меня объяснительная записка. И собственный вывод из ситуации:  вот уж не надо смешивать разные темы в одном ответе.